# Delete queue job after multiple timeouts in Laravel using Beanstalk

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a setup where sometimes a job will timeout. The problem is that it keeps hogging the queue and the other jobs won't run.

I want to delete the jobs which timeout 3 times and continue on with the queue. How can I do this? This is specific to laravel 4.2

Comment: Since I dont have an answer for you ill ask a few questions. Is there some way you could run multiple workers on your queue to take care of this? Aside from that, do you have something keeping track of timeouts? Do you have a way to programmatically kill a specific task based on data about the task (id number, etc)?

Comment: I haven't researched multiple queues. Not sure how that would help. I don't have anything keeping track of timeouts. That what I want. If I can somehow catch the timeout, I can just delete the job.

Comment: not multiple queues, multiple workers on the one queue you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$job` object has an `attempts` method that tells you how many times it tried to run:

```
public function fire($job, $data)
{
    // Try to process. If failed:

    if ($job->attempts() >= 3)
    {
        $job->delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does a timeout count as an attempt? Or is that the definition of it?

Comment: @Ortix92 - The first time the job runs will be the first attempt. If you don't delete it, it'll go back onto the queue. The next time a queue worker picks it up will be the second attempt. And so on...

Comment: What if the job is manually released back into the queue rather than on en exception? EG $job->release(); Does that add to the attempt count?

Comment: @Shane - I believe so. Yes.

Comment: @JosephSilber where do I put this code exactly? Do I put if condition in handle () function